# How can a OCW determine if a node is fully synced?

Tags: pallet, offchain-worker, sync

Is there a status-call/api that a OCW could invoke in order to establish if the actual running node instance is fully synced? Maybe listening to a `frame_system` event? Or knowing the total blocks number and comparing with the latest one? TIA.

NB: To better understand the UC, I have a RPC subscribed to an OCW. I want the RPC to be available, only once the node is fully synced. So I need the OCW to determine this before enabling the RPC calls.

Comment: You are asking from a Pallet? This does not make sense, a Pallet does not know anything about the chain except the block it is being executed in.

Comment: Sorry @ShawnTabrizi, It's a typo, I meant from an OCW perspective.

Comment: Makes much more sense! :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Adding to what Bryan said, you can just call the RPC `system.health`. The response `isSyncing` will be `false` if the node is in sync. No need for an OCW.

[image]

Comment: Thank you @joepetrowski, this is what I was really after. Would this `isSyncing` boolean remain `false` after `syncing`, but during new block importing? Cheers!

Comment: No, I'm not sure of the exact logic behind it, but I think once it's generally caught up (if the current block height is within `N` blocks of the highest known block) then it is not "syncing" anymore and is just doing normal block import to remain in sync.

Comment: Thanks @joepetrowski.

Answer (score 8):

OCW don't determine if a node is fully synced. It got notified by txpool when new block is imported

https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/97ee3d1de19e3f7442b6c0aa4ad360a49d5ea663/client/offchain/src/lib.rs#L225-L232

Note importing is different than syncing (bulk importing) so OCW are only invoked after the blockchain is fully synced.

This PR may have more context https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/5200

Not exactly sure what's your requirement but it doesn't sounds relating to OCW much. Your custom RPC handler should be able to query syncing status and decide what to do. OCW can't determine behaviour of RPC call.

If the goal is only enable certain RPC when the node is fully synced, you can just do it in the RPC handler without OCW at all.

Comment: Great answer @Brayn Chen, thank you.